# Tinymce Editor Extra Space while using powerpaste plugin

Tags: tinymce

I have integrated tinymce Editor with **power paste** plugin.
My problem is when i copy a line from word and with extra space at last then after pasting it in editor and selecting its option yes which says "Keep Formatting",
it creates extra p tag as follow:

```
<p style="text-align: justify; line-height: 150%; margin: 0cm 0cm 8pt; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: #0070c0;">
```

for extra space.

How to avoid this?
Please help me..

Comment: Sorry for that code mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the two options available:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea", 
    plugins: "powerpaste",
    powerpaste_word_import: "clean"
});
```

and

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea", 
    plugins: "powerpaste",
    powerpaste_html_import: "merge"
});
```

And check if it works now

Answer (score 0):

Yes this happens with me many times. Try this and it will help you

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea", 
    plugins: "powerpaste",
    powerpaste_html_import: "merge"
});
```

You can try PasteitCleaned external plugin which is an amazing plugin that handles copy/paste from Word, Excel, PowerPoint, PDF, Websites, Paint, etc. It’s available at $5/month. [Check out](https://www.pasteitcleaned.io/).

Comment: How are you affiliated with the proposed product? Please complete this in your answer. Otherwise, the post could be deleted because it is assumed that you want to advertise the product.